# Correct way to handle Error and display message after Graphql call

Tags: javascript

I am doing a GraphQL call to one of our APIs and im trying to handle some error in case users input some weird data.
The API returns an error structured in a way that I am not being able to handle and display the returned message.
[image]

And the way I am trying to display the message is as follow:

```
const onSubmit = async ({ inviteEmail, firstName, lastName }) => {
try {
  const result = await API.post('aaa', '/aaa', {
    body: {
      action: 'abc',
      inviteEmail,
      firstName,
      lastName,
    }
  });
  if(result) {
    history.push('/consent');
  }
  setLoading(false);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('message', error.message);
  setErrorMessage(error.message);
  setLoading(false);
}
```

}

So, I've tried some variants of the current error handling, like: `console.log(error[0].message)` or
`catch (({ message })) { console.log('message', message); }`
but none of them are displaying correct my error message.

So, what would be the best way to handle this response structure ?

Comment: Interesting related read: https://itnext.io/the-definitive-guide-to-handling-graphql-errors-e0c58b52b5e1

Comment: Concerning your specific case, I suppose `result` holds the data you're looking for, even if from within the `try` block (and not the `catch` block).

Comment: hey @sp00m thanks for your response. Unfortunately the `result` const doesn't hold the data in case the `try` fails.

Comment: What is the value of the `error` when you console.log it from within your catch block? Just `error`, not `error.message`

Comment: Assuming `API.post` only does a HTTP request, the `try`/`catch` will never fire for a GraphQL error. Those are located in `result.errors` (and as the screenshot shows, in an array - there might be multiple errors).